# Error Web scraping page does not reconnect, but can be started again

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy, http-proxy

I'm scraping a website, and sometimes it sends me this message, and does not reconnect to the target web page

```
2020-08-18 22:37:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:38:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 35 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 35 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:38:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:38:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:39:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:39:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:39:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:40:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:40:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:40:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:41:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:41:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:41:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:42:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:42:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:42:30 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2020-08-18 22:43:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 116421 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 116421 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-18 22:43:00 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 0, unchecked: 0, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
```

I use a rotational proxy, which is refreshed every hour. Try the proxy with another spider, and it works fine on the same page.
**What could be the problem?, How can I rescue the data that has already been scraped?**

Code:

```
import scrapy

class Pool(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pool'
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open("D:\links.txt").readlines()]

    def parse(self,response):
        pool1 = response.xpath("/html/[6]").get('').strip()
        url = response.url
        yield {
            'Pool1': pool1,
            'Url ': url ,
        }
```

Settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'Pool'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Pool.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Pool.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter',
}
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 3600
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
    'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = [
    'IPproxyhttp',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be that the page or all proxies disconnected at the same time, and are waiting for the DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT